# How to skip an excel line using in a loop in Java for a Selenium automation program

Tags: java, excel, selenium

I'm trying to make a selenium program to go online on a specific site,log in and then put in the search boxes places and addresses which I take from an excel file and when the search is complete to add a review on the site.However, some places are already reviewed and can't be reviewed again so my question is when a place is reviewed how to make it search again but take information from the NEXT excel cell rather than use the same one?I know there's probably a simple answer to this but I can't figure out how to search for it more specifically.I hope you can help me. Here is all my code.

```
public class Checkbot {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        //Open excel file
        String FilePath = "C:\\Users\\CandyGirl\\Documents\\DunkinDonuts1.6.2.xlsx";
    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(FilePath);
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
    //Access data sheet
    Sheet sh = wb.getSheet("Sheet6");

    //Loop through rows
    for( int count = 0;count <=sh.getLastRowNum();count++){
        Row row = sh.getRow(count);
        runTest(row.getCell(0).toString(),row.getCell(1).toString());
        boolean reviewed; 
        if(reviewed = true){
            count++;
        }
        }
    fs.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Test data file not found");
    }
    }


private static void runTest(String searchWhat, String searchWhere) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //Start browser driver to axs map website

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.axsmap.com/");
    //log in
    //click Log In button
    driver.findElement(By.id("nav-login")).click();
    //Enter username
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(username);
    //Enter password
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(password);
    //Press Enter to log in
    WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
    input.submit();
    //try to make it wait before it crashes
    waitForLoad(driver);
    //if after the login the page shows an application error just go back to the main page
    boolean myTitle = driver.getTitle().contains("Application Error");
    if (myTitle = true){
        driver.get("http://www.axsmap.com/");}
    //Enter search what and where and send it
    searchPlace(searchWhat, searchWhere, driver);
    //try to make it wait to load,if there's an error go back to front page and try again. 
    waitForLoad(driver);
    if (myTitle = true){
        driver.get("http://www.axsmap.com/");
        searchPlace(searchWhat,searchWhere,driver);}

    //when page loads to the map click add review
    driver.findElement(By.id("btn-add-review")).click();
    //If reviewed
    waitForLoad(driver);
    boolean reviewed = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#pg-addreview > div > div > div.w-form.venue-review-form > div")).isDisplayed();
    if (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#pg-addreview > div > div > div.w-form.venue-review-form > div")).isDisplayed()){
        searchPlace(searchWhat,searchWhere,driver);}
    //find and click on the 4 star rating
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#pg-addreview > div > div > div.w-form.venue-review-form > form > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div.row-value.w-col.w-col-9.entry-stars > div:nth-child(6)")).click();
    driver.close();
}


private static void searchPlace(String searchWhat, String searchWhere, WebDriver driver) {
    //Find and type in the search What field
    driver.findElement(By.id("search-what")).clear();
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("search-what"));
    element.sendKeys(searchWhat);
    //Find and type in the search Where field and press enter
    driver.findElement(By.id("search-where")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("search-where")).sendKeys(searchWhere);
    element.submit();
}

public static void waitForLoad(WebDriver driver) {
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> pageLoadCondition = new
            ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                    return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
                }
            };
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(pageLoadCondition);
}
```

}

Comment: Your code looks OK to me. What is happening? **`count++`** not working?

Comment: That works but when you run into a reviewed page and it does the search again what it types is the same thing it JUST searched,meaning that it doesn't move forward past the first excel line.I understand it may not be getting out of the first loop.

Comment: I think there is typo in all your `if` condition. you are using like `if(reviewed = true)` it is assignment you change these statement to comparison `==` like `if(reviewed == true)`

Comment: Make your Boolean **`reviewed`** public or return it from your **`runTest`** method and change `if(reviewed = true)` to `if(reviewed == true)`.

Comment: I changed that if statement but it still won't work the way I want it to.It just keeps searching for the same thing.

Comment: Don't have samples to test.  But can you try this first.  Under `Row row = sh.getRow(count);`, add `Cell cell = row.getCell();` and change the next line to `runTest(cell.toString(),cell.toString());`.  Also, just another thought, probably you want to check if the row or cell is empty to avoid errors.